# How can I navigate correctly from routes added in the Shell?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, routes, xamarin.forms.shell

I tried to use "/", "//" and "///" but none worked.

All code has been moved to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zehguilherme/55fed3d33fc3b7918dd44c3161d8faef).

Comment: You got any errors ? Have you followed the same example from Microsoft Docs and is not working ? When you are navigating? where TokenPage is consumed/used ?

Comment: Yes, with the examples I was able to understand more in general, but not in practice. I saw that in the examples you can use customized routes like "login / token" instead of the page itself. However, as the app has few pages, I thought it best to use them as the "name" of the routes. After validating the fields on the login page, the user is taken to the token page where he inserts what he receives by SMS.

Comment: I'm getting this error "Shell cannot push a page to the following type: KNotifyMobile.Views.LoginPage. The visible modal page needs to be a NavigationPage at Xamarin.Forms.ShellSection.GoToAsync".

Comment: What is the base class of your `TokenPage`?

Comment: It extends from ContentPage

Comment: Hi, `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoginPage));` not works?

Comment: No, I have tested it in every possible way and I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: @JoséGuilherme Could you share a sample project link here? I will check that in my local site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not consuming/instantiating the `TokenPage` inside your AppShell hierarchy than you probably need to use `Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new (TokenPage))` instead of `GoToAsync()`, because:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("monkeydetails");
```

> In this example, the monkeyDetails route is searched for up the hierarchy until the matching page is found. When the page is found, it's pushed to the navigation stack. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation)).

Comment: I debugged it but it ends up going straight through that line, even with await.

Comment: could you please update your question with the relevant code? including the method where you made the call to PushAsync

Comment: I tried to add the updated code but the stackoverflow complained that it had too much code. I created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/zehguilherme/55fed3d33fc3b7918dd44c3161d8faef) on github.

Comment: I am suspecting the issue coming from other parts of your code, the best thing to do to confirm that, is to comment-out all code and isolate the PushAsync  call alone to test it.

Comment: The problem that still exists is in this variable `_configuration`, which consults with the bank (checks if it is an update and such), but apart from that, when this part is working, when it reaches the navigation part for `TokenPage`, it still passes straight.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but thought I'd post a possible answer. Because the page isn't in your hierarchy, you need to register it in a navigation route first.

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TokenPage), typeof(TokenPage));
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#routes